# Find $f'(c)$ using the derivative definition for $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So $f:\mathbb R \backslash\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb R$ by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$

I'm need to use the definition of the derivative to find $f'(c)$ for $\frac{1}{x^2}$.  If I use standard differentiation techniques I get:

$-\frac{2}{c^3}$

However, using the following definition:

$f'(c) = \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$

I end up with $\frac{c^2-x^2}{x^2c^2(x-c)}$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the procedure of the derivation you did?

Comment: That definition needs to be $f'(c) = \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}$.

Comment: You still need to take the limit as $x\to c$; notice that $f^{\prime}(c)=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$.

Comment: See also: [Evaluating the limit if it exists of: $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{(x+h)^2} - \frac{1}{x^2}}{h}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/68273)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative is
$$
f'(c) = \lim_{x\to c }\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}
$$

You should do
$$
\lim_{x\to c}\frac{c^2-x^2}{x^2c^2(x-c)}=
\lim_{x\to c}\frac{(c-x)(c+x)}{x^2c^2(x-c)}=
\lim_{x\to c}-\frac{c+x}{x^2c^2}=-\frac{2}{c^3}
$$

Answer (score 2):

set $x-c=h$ then $$f^{ \prime  }\left( c \right) =\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { f\left( c+h \right) -f\left( c \right)  }{ h }  } =\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \frac { 1 }{ { \left( c+h \right)  }^{ 2 } } -\frac { 1 }{ { c }^{ 2 } }  }{ h }  } =$$ $$ \\ \\ =\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { { c }^{ 2 }-{ \left( c+h \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ { \left( c+h \right)  }^{ 2 }{ c }^{ 2 }h }  } =\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { -h\left( 2c+h \right)  }{ { \left( c+h \right)  }^{ 2 }{ c }^{ 2 }h }  } =\frac { -2 }{ { c }^{ 3 } } $$