# Find the derivative of $h(x) = 1/x^2$ by definition

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Can someone please explain the process of finding the derivative $h'(x)$ of 
$h(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^2} $

using the delta ($\Delta$) notation.

---

What I managed:

1. $h '(x) \displaystyle = \lim _{\Delta x\rightarrow 0} \frac{h(x+\Delta x)- h(x)}{\Delta x}$
2. $h '(x) \displaystyle = \lim _{\Delta x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1/(x+\Delta x)^2 - 1/x^2}{\Delta x}$
3. $h '(x) \displaystyle = \lim _{\Delta x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2-(x+\Delta x)^2}{(x+\Delta x)^2x^2\Delta x}$

And after this point, I do not know how to proceed.

The next steps have been given as:

4. $h '(x) \displaystyle  = \lim _{\Delta x\rightarrow 0} \frac{-2x\Delta x - (\Delta x)^2}{(x+\Delta x)^2x^2\Delta x}$
5. $h '(x) \displaystyle  = \lim _{\Delta x\rightarrow 0} \frac{-2x - \Delta x}{(x+\Delta x)^2x^2}$

With the answer being $h'(x) = -\dfrac{2}{x^{3}}$

Can someone please explain the process between steps 3 and 4?

Comment: [Using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim%20_%7Bh%5Crightarrow%200%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%2F(x%2Bh)%5E2%20-%201%2Fx%5E2%7D%7Bh%7D%24&p=1) I found [Find $f'(c)$ using the derivative definition for $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1850280) and [Evaluating the limit if it exists of: $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{(x+h)^2} - \frac{1}{x^2}}{h}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/68273). Duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\displaystyle x^2-(x+\Delta x)^2=x^2-(x^2+2x\Delta x+(\Delta x)^2)=-2x\Delta x-(\Delta x)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

just simplify the equation like : $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 => x^2 - (x +Δx) = x^2 - (x^2 + 2xΔx + Δx^2) = -2xΔx - Δx^2$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{h(x+\Delta{x})-h(x)}{\Delta{x}}=\frac{\frac{1}{(x+\Delta{x})^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}}{\Delta{x}}=\frac{\frac{1}{x^2+2x\Delta{x}+\Delta{x^2}}-\frac{1}{x^2}}{\Delta{x}}=\frac{-2x\Delta{x}-\Delta{x^2}}{(\Delta{x})(x^2)(x^2+2x\Delta{x}+\Delta{x^2})}=\frac{-2x-\Delta{x}}{x^4+2x^3\Delta{x}+x^2\Delta{x^2}}$$
and since $\Delta{x}$ tends to 0, this equals
$$\frac{-2x}{x^4}=\frac{-2}{x^3}$$